# Why is "Cold Iron" the only thing that can harm faeries?

Tags: magic

In Europe an folklore "Cold Iron" is used to repel spirits and malevolent creatures away. I took this idea and ran with it in my fantasy.
In my fantasy world fearies/fae are known as Aos and are a series of nature spirits and entities with most hailing from some sort of court. Many others are independent though such as: the Aos of specific forests, rivers, and mountains.
However much like their European counter parts the Aos are dangerous creatures who commonly prey on humans for their own amusement or for trivial offenses (not all Aos of course)
The Aos where virtually unkillable by humans, save the occasional unique weakness humans managed to exploit or beating Aos at their own game (riddles). But that all changed when the humans first worked Iron from meteorites. It was soon discovered that "Cold Iron" (worked iron) could not only harm the Aos, but also kill them. Wherever iron cut the Aos couldn't regenerate and left a permanent scar.
As the humans entered the iron age and began working iron ore the Aos where slowly driven away from human settlements and although initially the Aos attacked human towns in mass as a last ditch effort they eventually where forced from their forests and rivers and groves.

So what I'm wondering is why does Iron have this unique feature of harming the supernatural? I'll define cold iron as worked iron ex: tools, weapons, jewelry

Here's some criteria for answers:
It should include that the Aos are nature spirits and worked iron being"unnatural"

It should be a magical solution not necessarily physical/atomic. If you could include a way to have both that'd be sweet.

Note: The Aos can be thought of as nature spirits that embody chaos/madness. They don't have fixed forms and they appear as truly monstrous creatures. Think Norse Jotun specifically loki's children.

Aos function similar to the spirits from princess mononoke or avatar the last air bender: where they are tangible beings with "other worldly" forms. While they couldn't usually be killed before the forging of iron occasionally humans discovered a weakness: riddles, obligation to deals, discovering their true name, etc. However iron has the ability to kill and maim them the regular way: hacking off a limb, head, legs, etc. It also prevents the Aos from regenerating, which weapons like bronze where unable to do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101609/discussion-on-question-by-celestial-dragon-emperor-why-is-cold-iron-the-only-t).

Answer (score 4):

I'd posit that it's in the working itself.  Smith magic, you see.

Faeries (your Aos) are nature spirits and their nature is that of the caprice, the wild fury, the tranquil beauty of unspoilt Nature. All was well and good when Men were just a clever kind of beast.  But then came Prometheus...

***Wrought iron defies Nature***.  It is a dwimmery that the Faeriekind can not understand. In working this kind of magic, Men have (probably unwittingly) discovered another weapon that can be used against the chaos and madness of the Faeries.  Quite simply, Man ever seeks after his own nature: truth, beauty and good.  These are things of Order, and the dwimmery of smithcraft is Order on all levels from the discipline of physical & communal labour to the intellectual tranquility of "getting it just right" all the way down to the atomic alignment and ordering of the metal itself.

***Order vs Chaos***. The very nature of worked metal -- any kind of metal -- is a threat to the Faeries.  They probably don't mind wrought gold and silver, because even among Men these are used decoratively, as things of whimsy and chaos.  Bronze must have been a concern to the Faeries, because in bronze, Man was better able to bring order out of chaos.  But bronze is weak and only so much order can be made.  And so Faeriekind promptly forgot about what Men were up to.

But iron is a different matter.  It is strong, and the tools that Man made with it were strong: durable, able to cut and carve wood with ease, crush and shape stone with less effort. Here was a tool in the hands of a race oriented towards Order, and what Man became with that material struck an existential fear into the hearts of all Faeriekind, because here was a being that could rise up and set aside its own native fear of the powers of Nature!

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the (real world) mythology, fairies, witches, ghosts and such draw their power from and wield power over the *natural* elements. Iron that has been refined, forged, and wrought into a form by human hands is no longer *natural* in that same sense, and so these entities have no power over it.

I suspect pre-modern cultures would have noticed iron's odd coldness (which we now know is due to it's high heat conductivity) and assumed that it drains magical/etherial powers the same way it seems to drain heat, but that's just speculation.

Answer (score 2):

Iron is both conventionally magical (because of its magnetism) and deeply unmagical (because it is dead, tending not to change, unlike living things or other stones [other stones are breakable by tree roots, crack in sun, are easily reshaped, and wear down quickly by water]). This lends it a mythology of “magic over magic”. Iron drains heat when touched, which is akin to draining life. In pre-WWII society, it is nearly unique in its properties. For all these reasons, it is predisposed to be fairy bane. All it takes is one incident in which someone reports a fairy dying from touching iron, and that story will readily be believed. Whether the story is true or not doesn’t matter to the belief. All you have to do is decide that in your world, it is true.